# How to create a stopwatch (timer) on Apple Watch (iOS)

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos

Is there a way to create a timer that performs just like the Fitness app on watchOS or Clock app on iOS? More specifically, is there a dedicated SDK that lets you create timers with Swift? What's the suggested approach to doing that?

I know about the Timer class, but Timer only lets you listen for one-second changes, while the above-mentioned apps both have milliseconds timer.

Thanks!

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Timer` and set the `TimeInterval` which really is in seconds, but which is also an alias for double.

`typealias TimeInterval = Double`

This means you can put there value such as `0.02`.
Also remember, that timer might not be triggered precisely at the interval. There is a

`var tolerance: TimeInterval`

- The amount of time after the scheduled fire date that the timer may fire.

that can be configured for a timer instance.

For more info see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer